# How to fix play-store refuse app beacuse launcher icon size

Tags: android, google-play

I've uploaded my app to the play store and all was good, but suddenly I received an email from Google about problems in my icon launcher size. It's a real problem for me, because the app is for a venue, and the venue is in 3 days. I'm disrespected about this because I tried a lot of different changes but nothing appears to work. I tried to contact google play support to, but never received an answer :(

this is the email that Google sends me every 8 hours. (Because I upload a new version and work)

> Hi, Developers at the map,
>
> After review, Agroactiva, com.agroactiva.agrofy, has been removed from
>   Google Play because it violates the device and network abuse policy.
>   The large dimensions of your app's launcher icon negatively impact the
>   performance of some user devices.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Make changes to your app icon to bring your app into compliance. Your
>   app’s launcher icon size must not exceed 2048x2048. Read through the
>   Device and Network Abuse policy for more details, and make sure your
>   app complies with all policies listed in the Developer Program
>   Policies. Sign in to your Play Console and submit the policy compliant
>   update. If approved, your app will again be available with all
>   installs, ratings, and reviews intact.
>
> If you've reviewed our policies and feel this removal may have been in
>   error, please reach out to our policy support team. We'll get back to
>   you within 2 business days.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Review Team

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally i could find the problem :).

After various emails with Google team people, they said me that the problem of the icon size was in a very old apk in the a beta channel created a year ago. 
They never mention what apk version is wrong in the email, and I never imagin thst Google can remove an app beacuse a beta close channel has a invalid apk.
In resume, if you receive an email from Google removing your app, and in the email body you can't see the apk version, you need to check in beta or alpha channel too, not matter if the channel is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to actually change your icon size? If yes and you fit then this is strange. Google has been known for taking down developer accounts of apps that generate good revenue for no reason

Comment: the problem is that the icon size is ok, i did it with Android Studio assets generator

Comment: I opened the SDK with android studio too, and check all the assets one by one trying to find a big one.